# Understanding electric potential in the context of gravitational potential?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, potential, potential-energy

I'm trying to understand the concept of electric potential and the significance of an electric field being related to the gradient/derivative of an electric potential.

I found this question that explains how potential energy relates to force in the $-z$ direction - [Is force the derivative of energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161195/is-force-the-derivative-of-energy)

What would an analogous answer be for electric potential and force in one dimension?

Comment: Potential energy by defintion is $F=- \dfrac{dU}{dr}$. Where $F$ is the force, $U$ is potential energy and $r$ is position.

Answer (score 1):

The analogy would be voltage as the potential, so this would be analogous to height (as in the height of a rock of mass m in gravity field g).

Since power (which is also energy) is Voltage x Amps, then Amperes is analogous to mg.  If you want to break it down further, I guess mg = Q/sec.

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but it at least gets things started.